# Anomaly with bash PS1 definition

Tags: bash, command-line, prompt

My root and admin user both have the same `.bashrc` file.

The prompt section of the `.bashrc` is the following:

```
         if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
                PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ ' 
           else
                PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' 
         fi 
         unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

         # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir 
         case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)
                PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
                ;;
            *)
                ;; 
         esac
```

But the problem is that the admin user and root user have different prompts.

admin's prompt is:

> admin@hostname:~$

and root's prompt is

> root@hostname:/home#

So it seems root is using the "xterm" version and admin is not.

Why does the `.bashrc` file have this difference in prompts? How do I get the admin user to also use the xterm version?

How would I test that condition?

If I run `echo $TERM` while running as the admin user I get `xterm` so as far as I can tell, it should be using the xterm version for the admin user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as expected.

By convention, the prompt ends with `$` for users and by `#` for root. This is the `\$` in `PS1`.

The other difference is the `~` vs `/home`. This is also normal. It is the `\w` part of the prompt, the current working path. If it begins with the content of `$HOME`, it is replaced by `~`.