# Different behavior between non-root and root user using same PS1 env var

Tags: bash, ps1

I have slightly different behaviors between non-root and root users on the PS1 bash prompt:

```
~/Documents/infra-code (homologazure)$ echo $PS1
\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(parse_git_branch)\$

~/Documents/infra-code (homologazure)$ sudo su

/home/user/Documents/infra-code (homologazure)# echo $PS1
\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(parse_git_branch)\$
```

This answer says this is the expected behavior: [Anomaly with bash PS1 definition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28840/anomaly-with-bash-ps1-definition)

Now I want to standardize the same behavior for folder path between non-root and root users, so I would like to have ~/Documents/ instead of /home/user/Documents for root user. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The easiest way would be to set your `HOME` when `root` to match the value of `user`'s `HOME` by changing the command you call to become root (either via alias, function, or manually typing out `HOME=/home/user` after becoming root.

Comment: ok, this worked, but why and how?

Comment: Because `root` has a different `HOME`. `root` is a different user on the machine. The prompt being displayed truncates the *current user*'s home to `~` if it is present in `$PWD`. However, `HOME` is just a variable, and you can set it to something else if you'd like, so you can change it and the PS1 will check that your directory starts with your `HOME` and replace that section of your path with `~`.